# How to define this custom set of keywords?

Tags: macros

In the MWE bellow I want to have a command like

```
\keywords{one \and two \and three foo bar \and four $x^2$-foo}
```

which gives me this output:
[image]
**How to define such a command?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{abstract}
%\keywords{one \and two \and three foo bar \and four $x^2$-foo}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your post does not say `No extra packages` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\and\\
    \par
    \noindent\textbf{Keywords:}\\#1\par
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
        Lorem ipsum...
\end{abstract}
\keywords{one \and two \and three foo bar \and four $x^2$-foo}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the definition

```
\newcommand\keywords[1]%
  {\begin{flushleft}
   \let\and\\%
   \textbf{Keywords:}\\
   #1
   \end{flushleft}%
  }
```

to your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\keywords[1]%
  {\begin{flushleft}
   \let\and\\%
   \textbf{Keywords:}\\
   #1
   \end{flushleft}%
  }

\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{abstract}
\keywords{one \and two \and three foo bar \and four $x^2$-foo}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```